# Is it possible to show the number of favorites or retweets on TWTRTimelineViewController?

Tags: twitter-fabric

I'm using Fabric's TwitterKit to display a specified user's twitter timeline on my iOS app. I'm able to display the feed successfully following the directions on Fabric's Mac OS app.

But I would like to know if it's possible to show the number of favorites or retweets on the TWTRTimelineViewController. I don't see any properties on that VC to display said info. I don't see any info about that on Fabric's TwitterKit documentation as well.